# AUTH_FAILED for OpenVPN Cloud account

Tags: openvpn

I created a new account on OpenVPN Cloud and added a device to my account. Afterwards, I downloaded the profile file (.ovpn-file) and trying to establish the VPN connection using the following comment:

```sh
> sudo openvpn --config device_1_someuser\@somemail_com\@someuser.openvpn.com_Frankfurt.conf

Fri Jul  9 21:03:19 2021 OpenVPN 2.4.7 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [LZ4] [EPOLL] [PKCS11] [MH/PKTINFO] [AEAD] built on Sep  1 2020
Fri Jul  9 21:03:19 2021 library versions: OpenSSL 1.1.1d  10 Sep 2019, LZO 2.10
Fri Jul  9 21:03:19 2021 Outgoing Control Channel Authentication: Using 256 bit message hash 'SHA256' for HMAC authentication
Fri Jul  9 21:03:19 2021 Incoming Control Channel Authentication: Using 256 bit message hash 'SHA256' for HMAC authentication
Fri Jul  9 21:03:19 2021 TCP/UDP: Preserving recently used remote address: [AF_INET]84.16.x3x.1x9:1194
Fri Jul  9 21:03:19 2021 Socket Buffers: R=[2097152->2097152] S=[212992->212992]
Fri Jul  9 21:03:19 2021 NOTE: setsockopt TCP_NODELAY=1 failed
Fri Jul  9 21:03:19 2021 UDP link local: (not bound)
Fri Jul  9 21:03:19 2021 UDP link remote: [AF_INET]84.16.x3x.1x9:1194
Fri Jul  9 21:03:19 2021 TLS: Initial packet from [AF_INET]84.16.x3x.1x9:1194, sid=524e7b5f b8d21118
Fri Jul  9 21:03:19 2021 VERIFY OK: depth=1, CN=CloudVPN Prod CA
Fri Jul  9 21:03:19 2021 VERIFY KU OK
Fri Jul  9 21:03:19 2021 Validating certificate extended key usage
Fri Jul  9 21:03:19 2021 ++ Certificate has EKU (str) TLS Web Server Authentication, expects TLS Web Server Authentication
Fri Jul  9 21:03:19 2021 VERIFY EKU OK
Fri Jul  9 21:03:19 2021 VERIFY OK: depth=0, CN=eu-central-2b.cloud.openvpn.net
Fri Jul  9 21:03:19 2021 Control Channel: TLSv1.3, cipher TLSv1.3 TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, 2048 bit RSA
Fri Jul  9 21:03:19 2021 [eu-central-2b.cloud.openvpn.net] Peer Connection Initiated with [AF_INET]84.16.x3x.1x9:1194
Fri Jul  9 21:03:20 2021 SENT CONTROL [eu-central-2b.cloud.openvpn.net]: 'PUSH_REQUEST' (status=1)
Fri Jul  9 21:03:20 2021 AUTH: Received control message: AUTH_FAILED,SSO Auth Failed due to lack of client support
Fri Jul  9 21:03:20 2021 SIGTERM[soft,auth-failure] received, process exiting
```

But as you can see I'm the message "AUTH: Received control message: AUTH_FAILED,SSO Auth Failed due to lack of client support". I also already tried to use `--auth-user-pass`-parameter. But the error message remains to be the same. For the "--auth-user-pass"-parameter I used the parameters of my owner account (email address and account password). I hope that's correct but I'm not sure if I even need this...

Is anyone having any idea how I can solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I was finally able to connect using OpenVPN. The problem was that I was using OpenVPN 2.4.7 but I had to use OpenVPN 3 instead.

Comment: I just installed openvpn3 but syslog tells me I'm using 2.5.1. How did you force it to use v3?

Comment: Is possible to connect to OpenVPN Cloud using Network Manager integration? (Realted to this question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1396992/is-openvpn-connection-when-a-saml-2-0-auth-is-required-supported-in-network-mana)